# Cycling through tmux panes in reverse order of `C-b o`

Tags: tmux

`C-b o` lets you cycles through all the panes. `C-b ;` lets you go to the previously active pane, which means if you use it twice then you get back to the current pane and not previous previously active pane.

Is there a keybinding/way to set my own keybinding which goes through pane similarly to `C-b o` but in reverse order?

Answer (score 1):

While writing this question, I found the answer to it on my own so I thought I'd use SE's answer-your-own-question

Look at `man tmux` and search for (by hitting `/`) `select-pane`. It specifies many options, one of which is `-t` which lets you specify the pane number.

Though not explicitly specified, in many places tmux accepts relative offsets, so while `-t 0` will go to 0th pane, `-t +1` seems to go to next pane no mater where you currently are, and it cycles too.

So find a key which is unbound, you can use `C-b ?` and scroll down to prefix key section there to find such a key. I found `a` to be unbound to anything.

And then add this to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key a select-pane -t -1
```

And that's it.